# I need to translate a couple of Oracle DECODES to SQL Server - does anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have the following Oracle code which I'm trying to translate to SQL Server.

```
MAX (DECODE (MX.MAXHIER - ANC.HIERARCHYLEVELS, 0, WO.STATUS)) L1STATUS,
MAX (DECODE (MX.MAXHIER - ANC.HIERARCHYLEVELS, 0, WO.TARGSTARTDATE)) L1TARGSTARTDATE,
MAX (DECODE (MX.MAXHIER - ANC.HIERARCHYLEVELS, 0, WO.WORKTYPE)) L1TYPE,
MAX (DECODE (MX.MAXHIER - ANC.HIERARCHYLEVELS, 0, WO.WOPRIORITY)) L1WOPRIORITY,
MAX (DECODE (MX.MAXHIER - ANC.HIERARCHYLEVELS, 0, WO.CREWID)) L1CREWID,
```

The only quick solution I can think of is this but there must be a better solution.

```
MAX (CASE MX.MAXHIER - ANC.HIERARCHYLEVELS WHEN 0 THEN WO.STATUS END) L1STATUS
MAX (CASE MX.MAXHIER - ANC.HIERARCHYLEVELS WHEN 0 THEN WO.TARGSTARTDATE END) L1TARGSTARTDATE,
MAX (CASE MX.MAXHIER - ANC.HIERARCHYLEVELS WHEN 0 THEN WO.WORKTYPE END) L1TYPE,
MAX (CASE MX.MAXHIER - ANC.HIERARCHYLEVELS WHEN 0 THEN WO.WOPRIORITY END) L1WOPRIORITY,
MAX (CASE MX.MAXHIER - ANC.HIERARCHYLEVELS WHEN 0 THEN WO.CREWID END) L1CREWID,
MAX (CASE MX.MAXHIER - ANC.HIERARCHYLEVELS WHEN 0 THEN WO.TARGCOMPDATE END) L1TARGCOMPDATE,
MAX (CASE MX.MAXHIER - ANC.HIERARCHYLEVELS WHEN 0 THEN WO.LOCATION END) L1LOCATION,
```

I know there is probably a easier solution would love any help.

Comment: Please can you edit your question to clarify what would make the solution 'better' or 'easier'? What's wrong with the solution you already have? Does it not behave as expected? Does it cause performance problems? etc. If you edit the question to explain what's wrong with it, people will find it easier to know how to help you.

Comment: What do you mean by "easier" or "better" solution? `CASE` already is the standard way for such conditional expressions, so in terms of platform independence it already is the best solution. `CASE` would work in Oracle too, so the improvement might be to also use `CASE` in Oracle instead of `decode()`.

Comment: Hm... wouldn't it be much simpler to use something like `SELCT MAX(WO.STATUS END) L1STATUS, MAX(......) FROM... WHERE MX.MAXHIER - ANC.HIERARCHYLEVELS = 0`? Otherwise I agree with the other comments - `CASE` is the tool of choice here...

Answer (score 0):

A `CASE` state statement is definitely the way to go, but why subtract `MX.MAXHIER` and `ANC.HIERARCHYLEVELS`? You can just compare the values in the case statement to get the resulting column.

```sql
MAX (CASE MX.MAXHIER WHEN ANC.HIERARCHYLEVELS THEN WO.STATUS END) L1STATUS,
MAX (CASE MX.MAXHIER WHEN ANC.HIERARCHYLEVELS THEN WO.TARGSTARTDATE END) L1TARGSTARTDATE,
MAX (CASE MX.MAXHIER WHEN ANC.HIERARCHYLEVELS THEN WO.WORKTYPE END) L1TYPE,
MAX (CASE MX.MAXHIER WHEN ANC.HIERARCHYLEVELS THEN WO.WOPRIORITY END) L1WOPRIORITY,
MAX (CASE MX.MAXHIER WHEN ANC.HIERARCHYLEVELS THEN WO.CREWID END) L1CREWID,
MAX (CASE MX.MAXHIER WHEN ANC.HIERARCHYLEVELS THEN WO.TARGCOMPDATE END) L1TARGCOMPDATE,
MAX (CASE MX.MAXHIER WHEN ANC.HIERARCHYLEVELS THEN WO.LOCATION END) L1LOCATION,
```